# Code works properly but showing INFO: Detected dialect: W3C error

Tags: automated-testing, selenium, selenium-webdriver, geckodriver

```
1502091713068   geckodriver::marionette INFO    Starting browser C:\Program Files\Mozilla Firefox\firefox.exe with args ["-marionette"]
1502091717606   Marionette  INFO    Listening on port 51394
Aug 07, 2017 12:41:58 PM org.openqa.selenium.remote.ProtocolHandshake createSession
INFO: Detected dialect: W3C
```

Code works properly but showing INFO: Detected dialect: W3C error

Answer (score 3):

It is not an ERROR, but INFO it just information shown in the log of the driver.

Most loggers have log-levels, INFO is just one you can ignore most of the time:

> INFO  Designates informational messages that highlight the progress of
>   the application at coarse-grained level.
>
> https://www.tutorialspoint.com/log4j/log4j_logging_levels.htm

The dialect is an internal WebDriver thing you could research it, but I think you should not worry about it.